# Currency conversion from 3 character code (USD) to their symbol as output ($) in magento 2?

Tags: custom, currency, currency-symbol

Does magento 2 is having something inbuilt function for currency symbol getting ? 
What I want is - Input will be 3 characters currency code as USD, INR, JPY, EUR etc.  corresponsing to that output should be $ , ₹ , ¥  etc...

All the solutions are appreciated even if its inbuilt in magento 2 or custom function or some API. 
**Edit - Code Added**
At the position `echo $ocd;` it gives me USD after that I need to print $, it may give Euro then I need to echo € and so on..

```
$detail_query_1="SELECT a.quote_id,a.entity_id,a.state,a.status,a.coupon_code,a.shipping_description,a.order_currency_code,a.discount_amount,a.customer_id,a.base_discount_amount,a.base_grand_total,a.base_shipping_amount,DATE_FORMAT(a.created_at,'%d-%m-%Y') AS order_date,a.total_item_count,b.increment_id FROM rpt_sales_order AS a JOIN rpt_sales_order_grid AS b ON a.entity_id=b.entity_id WHERE 1 AND b.increment_id='$ids'";
 //echo $detail_query_1;//exit;
 $sql_detail_1=mysqli_query($con,$detail_query_1) or die(mysqli_error($con));
 if(@mysqli_num_rows($sql_detail_1))
 { 
  $cnt1=@mysqli_num_rows($sql_detail_1);
  while($rt_details_1=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_detail_1,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
  {
   #print_r($rt_details);exit;
   $ordDt=$rt_details_1['order_date']; 
   $shpDesc=$rt_details_1['shipping_description']; 
   $ocd=  $rt_details_1['order_currency_code'];
   echo $ocd;
   $discount_amount=  $rt_details_1['discount_amount'];
  }

echo '<h3 class="shipping-method">Shipping Method: '.$shpDesc.'</h3>';
 }
```

Thanks
Vibhore

Comment: @Mital Shah - I added the code also for your reference at echo $ocd; i need some changes after that to display the currency symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Set your symbol currency from admin settings
Store -> Currency -> Currency Symbols**
[image: Currency Symbol Setup]

**As per you question try below code**

```
$currency = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory')->create()->load($currencyCode);
$currencySymbol = $currency->getCurrencySymbol();
```

As per your requirement,
Add this code in php file at Magento root folder and run through Magento URL. For example: You file name script.php and run magentostore.com/script.php

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
 
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
 
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
 
$currencyCode = 'your_code';
$currency = $objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory')->create()->load($currencyCode);
echo $currencySymbol = $currency->getCurrencySymbol();

?>
```

Comment: I added the code also, please check this question again.

Comment: @VibhoreJain I edit my answer, please check.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but May i get the equivalent code in pure php(not magento) ? I have .php file outside the magento scope..

Comment: Please keep this current code also(it is also useful) and just expand your answer to show me the code for pure php file also.

Comment: @VibhoreJain Check updated ans. And add your custom code in same file.

Comment: perfect , its working now, thanks a lot :) I accepted the answer.

Comment: For your information - I cut/paste "use and require" top 2 lines into the top of my php file that removed error 500 .. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Those who uses plain php then they can take the code from here -

```
$orderDetailsQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT a.sku,a.product_id,b.order_currency_code,b.entity_id,a.order_id,b.customer_email,b.increment_id,a.name,a.created_at,a.weight,a.qty_ordered,a.base_original_price,c.firstname,c.lastname,c.postcode,c.street,c.city,c.telephone,c.country_id,c.address_type,c.company,d.status,d.expected_close_time, d.couriers,d.tracking_no,e.postcode AS bill_postcode,e.street AS bill_street,e.city AS bill_city,e.country_id AS bill_country,f.cc_last_4,f.method FROM rpt_sales_order_item AS a INNER JOIN rpt_sales_order AS b ON a.order_id=b.entity_id INNER JOIN rpt_sales_order_address AS c ON b.entity_id=c.parent_id AND c.address_type='shipping' INNER JOIN rpt_sales_order_address AS e ON b.entity_id=e.parent_id AND e.address_type='billing' INNER JOIN rpt_sales_order_payment AS f ON b.entity_id=f.parent_id LEFT JOIN rpt_order_management AS d ON b.increment_id=d.order_id AND d.status='Shipped' WHERE b.increment_id=".$_POST['OrderData']."";
   
   // echo $orderDetailsQuery;
   $OrderRes = mysqli_query($conn, $orderDetailsQuery);

   while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($OrderRes)){
      // var_dump($rows);
      $ksb_currency= $rows['order_currency_code'];

      $formatter = new NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
   $ksb_currency_symbol = $formatter->formatCurrency(34634, $ksb_currency);
```